# Getting bid responses per request [prebid.js]

Tags: javascript, prebid.js

I was going through the prebid.js [documentation](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.getBidResponses) and couldn't find an option to
get a response per adapter the second it's done. As it looks, I have to wait for all the adapters to be done and only then can I use the response.
This is the snippet I'm using today:

```
 hb.que.push(() => {
            hb.addAdUnits(adUnits);
                hb.requestBids({
                // This callback gets triggered when all bids for this ad unit come back.
                bidsBackHandler: (bidResponses) => {
                   // Do some stuff
                },
            });
        });
```

Is there an API method I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create event listener for bidResponse event using pbjs.onEvent() as described in [Publisher API Reference](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.onEvent).